# PHP collecting user input and displaying it

Tags: php, html

So I have this basic program that allows you to collect user input and output it back to user or in other words display back in the browser but also lets you delete the object with the onClick method. so this basically is a very simple Todo list.

My problem is how do I collect the information and display each previous information in rows on the page instead of everything going away when the browser is refreshed. I know something like this would be ideal for a database but I'm trying to keep it simple and my knowledge of databases thus far is inadequate. I feel like PHP or even Javascript can resolve this issue but is just not clicking for me. Maybe a for loop or while loop could do the job not sure, I could use some help. thanks.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["user"])) {
    $user_info = $_POST["user"];
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Manage Todos</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="user"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Post">


    </form>

    <h1><a href="#" onclick="remove(this)"><?php echo $user_info;?> <?php echo $collect; ?></a></h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use session to store previous variable in order to be displayed again when page is refreshed.

Change your code to below : 
    if (isset($_POST["user"])) {
        $_SESSION["user_info"] = $_POST["user"];
    }

Also change your `<h1>` to below :

```
<h1><a href="#" onclick="remove(this)"><?php if (isset($_SESSION["user_info"])) echo $_SESSION["user_info"]; ?></a></h1>
```

Or you could change `<h1>` to :

```
<?php
  if (isset( $_SESSION["user_info"])) {
?>
    <h1><a href="#" onclick="remove(this)"><?php echo $_SESSION["user_info"]; ?></a></h1>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Hopefully this help.

---

**UPDATE**

Sorry, forgot to tell that you should start session first. Here is the right code :

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST["user"])) {
    $_SESSION["user_info"] = $_POST["user"];
}
?>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Assuming your url site is 015_session_variable.php.

Change your code to this :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST["user"])) {
        $_SESSION["old_user_info"] = isset($_SESSION["new_user_info"]) ? $_SESSION["new_user_info"] : "";
        $_SESSION["new_user_info"] = $_POST["user"];
    }
    if (isset($_GET["remove"])) {
        if ($_GET["remove"] == "new")
            $_SESSION["new_user_info"] = "";
        else 
            $_SESSION["old_user_info"] = "";
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Manage Todos</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="015_session_variable.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="user" required></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>

<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION["new_user_info"]) && $_SESSION["new_user_info"] != "") {
?>
    <h1><a href="#" onclick="removeMe('new');" title="Remove Me">Latest User : <?php echo $_SESSION["new_user_info"]; ?></a></h1>
<?php
    }
?>

<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION["old_user_info"]) && $_SESSION["old_user_info"] != "") {
?>
    <h1><a href="#" onclick="removeMe('old');" title="Remove Me">Previous User : <?php echo $_SESSION["old_user_info"]; ?></a></h1>
<?php
    }
?>
    <script>
        function removeMe(a) {
            window.open('015_session_variable.php?remove=' + a, '_self');
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you have information about :

1. How to create session
2. How to store variables in session
3. How to modify session's variables

Basically all you need are already in this code. Just utilize them as imaginable as possible. Good luck.

Comment: Hi Shire, it's different. Assuming your page is http://testsite.com. Now submit your form with user_info, lets say, "Hi There.". And then open your site by type your url's browser to your site (don't refresh). You will see "Hi There" in your page. That's one among many benefit from our beloved $_SESSION.

Comment: Also don't forget to add session_start(). Please refer to my updated answer.

Comment: I see what you mean that works but not what I was asking for lol basically if you submit something in the input field it will display and once it displays it and you enter something new in that old thing disappears with the new submit information. I want to be able to submit something new and still keep the old submitted thing does that make sense? but this works for a different reason.

Answer (score -1):

HTML5 can do that for you. Check this,

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

HTML5 provides offline storage in browser. You can use cookies also but web storage is better option in your case.